# three pdf-documents in one appendix

Tags: pdflatex

Hallo,

I wanted to ask how I can join three different pdf documents so that it appears in one single appendix. The command I gave was:

```
See Appendix~\ref{sec:corr-1}~\ref{sec:corr-2}~\ref{sec:corr-3}
```

and I have the following on my appendixes list:

```
\subsubsection{Writing}
\label{sec:writing}
\input{corr-1.tex}
\input{corr-2.tex}
\input{corr-3.tex}
```

Unforunately I cannot compile the final document.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Have a nice day.

Marie

Comment: Has this issue been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

In your example you just include tex files. 
Have a look at the package pdfpages:  http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf

Add to the top of your document:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

You should call this in the text where you want the PDF to appear:

```
\includepdf{test.pdf}
```